# Html form not submitting more than 3 images with enctype=multipart/form-data

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a PHP based application in which we are getting large amount of data including more than 5 images. The code was working fine for many days but now it just stopped working. When we click the submit button the page reloads but the form does not submit to PHP POST Method. When i remove enctype from form then it gets submitted but the images doesn't pass. And with enctype it is only working with 3 images. if i increase the number of images it stops working.

***Code of my application:***

```
      <form role="form" name="app_form" id="app_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div id="application_form"> <!-- Application Form Starts Here -->

  <div class="container-fluid">

  <div style="margin-top: 10px; border-top: 3px solid #37A8B3; padding-top: 10px;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" >Applied For:</label>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="app_for" id="app_for" required>
          </div>

          <label class="control-label col-md-1">ID No:</label>
          <div class="col-md-2">          
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_id" required>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">

    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Upload1:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="file" name="Upload_1" id="Upload_1" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Upload2:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="file" name="Upload_2" id="Upload_2" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Upload3:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="file" name="Upload_3" id="Upload_3" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Upload4:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="file" name="Upload_4" id="Upload_4" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Upload5:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="file" name="Upload_5" id="Upload_5" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Upload6:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="file" name="Upload_6" id="Upload_6" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Upload7:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="file" name="Upload_7" id="Upload_7" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: #37A8B3;">
    <h4 style="padding: 5px; color: white;"> PLEASE COMPLETE IN BLOCK CAPITALS </h4>
    </div>

    <div style="border-bottom: 3px solid #37A8B3;">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-lg-2">Title Mr/Mrs/Ms/Other:</label>
          <div class="col-md-1">          
            <select class="form-control" name="user_title" required>
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-md-1" >First Name:</label>
          <div class="col-md-2">          
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_fname" required >
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-md-1" >Mid Name:</label>
          <div class="col-md-2">          
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_midname">
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-md-1" >Surname:</label>
          <div class="col-md-2">          
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_surname">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3" >Maiden/Former Name<small><i> (List all previous first names and surnames)</i></small>:</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">          
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_formername" required>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" >Current Address:</label>
          <div class="col-md-6 input-group-md">          
            <textarea class="form-control" name="user_curr_addr" rows="2" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-md-1" >Postcode:</label>
          <div class="col-md-3 input-group-sm">          
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_curr_post_code" required>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" name="submit_app" value="Submit Application">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- Application Form Ends Here -->
  </form>
```

Comment: Where is your code???

Comment: can u please post ur code / show the demo of ur application...

Comment: Kindly check the code i have updated.

Answer (score 1):

May be at first you tried small images and 5 pieces of small JPEGs didn't exceed your request size, then. Now, you're trying with bigger files and the total of your files are exceeding your request size value, thus you cannot complete your POST requests.

You should have got an error on the way somewherei though, but anyway.

I believe you should increase the request size in you PHP settings. Check the value of request size is bigger than the total size of files you're trying to POST.

I cannot provide you any code, because your question doesn't have any. I am just trying to help you out by pointing where to look.

EDIT:

As I am not a PHP expert, I know that the post size can be changed when you play with the "upload_max_filesize = xxM" and "post_max_size = xxM" which are located in the "PHP.ini" configuration file in your PHP installation directory. These are global values, though. If you're using a hosting panel, chances are you will find PHP specific settings in your panel. Just change or add these settings in order to override the global ones.

Comment: And what that code is telling me? I adviced you to change some PHP setting and you wrote you HTML code. Please do what I wrote you, then come back and tell us if it worked, ok?

Comment: Kindly guide me how to change the POST request size. i am using vertrigo serv.

Comment: I have tried changing the request limit. it was set to 8M i changed it to 16M but it is still not submitting data.

Comment: In my edit, I provided 2 different values for you to change. Are you sure that you changed both? May be somehow a restart is required!?

Comment: Yes i have changed both the values